# A Story of Secrets

Tags: riddle, story

> I was the child of a ruler, but I wasn't human
>
> All of my kind shared the same, strange weakness.
>
> We loved to be kidnapped by others.
>
> We would speak all of our secrets to them.
>
> Some see it as a weakness, but to us, it fulfilled our purpose.
>
> I was the best at it.
>
> But eventually, my speech began to fade.
>
> It inhibited me from fulfilling my purpose.
>
> Many in my kind had kept themselves young.
>
> But I, had let age defeat my purpose.
>
> My son carries on my purpose now.
>
> But I know even my son will fade just as I did.

***What am I?***

Hint 1:

> My son's name isn't old.

Hint 2:

> My sides can boast gold or silver.

Hint 3:

> Many in our kind have their names shown on their chests.

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> **Vinyl/LP record**?

I was the child of a ruler, but I wasn't human

> I think of *His Master's Voice* HMV as one of the leading record companies

All of my kind shared the same, strange weakness.
We loved to be kidnapped by others.

> LPs were shared (i.e. taken) by others

We would speak all of our secrets to them.
Some see it as a weakness, but to us, it fulfilled our purpose.

> LPs would allow music/lyrics/speech to be played back

I was the best at it.

> LPs were at one time the most popular format

But eventually, my speech began to fade.
It inhibited me from fulfilling my purpose.

> Due to wear/scratches they fade in quality

Many in my kind had kept themselves young.
But I, had let age defeat my purpose.

> Other kind of playback formats were cassettes/magnetic tape which became popular after LPs

My son carries on my purpose now.

> The compact disc can be thought of as the successor to LPs, as they employ roughly similar techniques (i.e. grooves cut on a disc) with differences (e.g. the grooves are digital)

But I know even my son will fade just as I did.

> CDs are being/have been supplanted by digital media and streaming services

Comment: This is a great answer, but its not the right one. I'll add some hints for clarification.

Comment: Cheers, @LordPrism

Answer (score 4):

Based on Puzzled Pig's [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63633/46886), are you

> a set of encyclopedia

I was the child of a ruler, but I wasn't human

> one of first general knowledge encyclopedias was written by [Pliny the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_encyclopedias)

All of my kind shared the same, strange weakness.

> All books are subject to damage from fire/water/age

We loved to be kidnapped by others.

> An encyclopedia was a large/expensive purchase.  It was common to be purchased by a group for group usage.  Or borrow the ones from the library.

We would speak all of our secrets to them.

> people read to learn all the information contained.

Some see it as a weakness, but to us, it fulfilled our purpose.

> the purpose of an encyclopedia is to relay the knowledge it contains.

I was the best at it.

> Encyclopedias were best at relaying knowledge because they contained information on many topics.

But eventually, my speech began to fade.

> Three reasons here: 1) the ink would fade.  2) the knowledge would need updated.  3) the hardcopy book format getting replaced by the internet/online resources.

It inhibited me from fulfilling my purpose.

> no longer able to pass along information when 1)the ink is faded out. 2)the knowledge is out of date. 3)the internet/online resources make hardcopy publishing no longer economically viable.

Many in my kind had kept themselves young.

> Publishing new versions/yearly "Year Book" updates/Moving to Online/CD/DVD versions.

But I, had let age defeat my purpose.

> didn't transfer to online/digital publishing and went bankrupt.

My son carries on my purpose now.

> Wikipedia

But I know even my son will fade just as I did.

> Everything changes.  Something will eventually replace wikipedia.

Comment: Great answer, but unfortunately incorrect. The weakness and kidnapping are both correlated to each other, and it speaks of a different kind of ruler.

Comment: @LordPrism Are you saying that the strange weakness is that they loved to be kidnapped and we need to explain that?

Answer (score 3):

I think perhaps you're a specific element of this broader category (I can't figure out a few of the clues), but are you a:

> book?

I was the child of a ruler, but I wasn't human

> ?

All of my kind shared the same, strange weakness.
We loved to be kidnapped by others.
We would speak all of our secrets to them.
Some see it as a weakness, but to us, it fulfilled our purpose.

> One could argue that almost all books are designed with the purpose of being read, and speaking the secrets within their pages to their reader.

I was the best at it.
But eventually, my speech began to fade.
It inhibited me from fulfilling my purpose.

> The ink of well-read book often starts to fade, making it harder to read (it can also be inhibited by the binding starting to break, etc.)

Many in my kind had kept themselves young.
But I, had let age defeat my purpose.

> Some books stay in good condition despite age (either through higher-quality construction, or lack of use, or both)

My son carries on my purpose now.
But I know even my son will fade just as I did.

> If your son is perhaps a sequel, or rewriting of the text within your pages, he will carry on your legacy, but eventually suffer the same problems.

Hint 1:

> ?

Hint 2:

> Books often have the sides of their pages painted gold or silver.

Hint 3:

> The spine and/or the cover of a book often bears its name.

Comment: Your pretty close, but your also right that its something more specific. Think about the significance of the ruler and the son's name.

Comment: Do either the original object or its son have religious significance?

Comment: I bet it has to do with a type of book for which the information within is time-dependent and subject to updates....

Answer (score 1):

Are you a:

> Password?

I was the child of a ruler, but I wasn't human

> Password is created by ruler of Roman military?

All of my kind shared the same, strange weakness.

> the weakness of being exploited easily?

We loved to be kidnapped by others.

> Hackers would love to

We would speak all of our secrets to them.

> Contents secured behind password

Some see it as a weakness, but to us, it fulfilled our purpose.

> security breach?

I was the best at it.
But eventually, my speech began to fade.

> Passwords are more easily guessed now

It inhibited me from fulfilling my purpose.

> Where it purpose is defeated

Many in my kind had kept themselves young.

> Renew password every once a while

But I, had let age defeat my purpose.

> Outdated password / password that didn't change for long

My son carries on my purpose now.

> The next password

But I know even my son will fade just as I did.

> Eventually it will be expired as well

Comment: Your reasoning for the last few lines actually were quite interesting, but your answer is wrong. Passwords wouldn't want to be kidnapped, since that would defeat their purpose (keeping something secure). Try to discover a possible purpose that would explain the weakness they have. If you haven't already, I'd also suggest reading the hints.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Rosetta Stone?

Since

> Original is the stone, the son is the software?  Both share how to translate, but the need to decrease as a more "universal" language becomes the norm much as the original faded from time, damage, and erosion.
>  The original was "stolen" (now at the British Museum).

Comment: Nope. I'll say two things that might help you. There is a difference about **wanting** to be stolen, and just being stolen. There is also a notable difference between _speech_ and _speaking_.

Answer (score -1):

I apologize, I do not know how to format to quote the riddle, but I am thinking:

> the Bill of Rights.

It is

> the product (son) of British rule.

Its son would be

> the Constitution. Over time the Bill of Rights became out dated and thus the Constitution was created and took its place. Eventually over time the Constitution may also become outdated and need to be redone and or replaced.

Comment: Good answer, but there is nothing that would suggest that the Bill of Rights would want to be stolen. If you haven't already, I suggest looking at one or more of the hints.